# File transfer stops after transmission of a certain amount of bytes

Tags: java, networking

I am currently working on a file transfer program and I ran into a strange issue.
I have two classes: A sender class and a recipient class. You can read the source code along with the error message below.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Sender:

```
public static void sendFile(final File file, final String ip){


Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(ip, 4816);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            String filename = file.getName();

            if(!dis.readUTF().equals("end")){

                dos.writeUTF(filename);
                dos.flush();

                long size = file.length();
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];

                int read;

                dos.writeUTF(Long.toString(size));
                dos.flush();


                while((read = fis.read(b)) != -1){
                    dos.write(b, 0, read);
                    dos.flush();
                }
                fis.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.writeUTF("end");
                System.out.println("Sender: Done");
                dos.flush();

                dis.close();
                dos.close();
                s.close();              
            }

            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
t.start();


}
```

Recipient:

```
private ServerSocket sock;
private Thread t;

public listener(){
    try {
        sock = new ServerSocket(4816);
        listen();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void listen(){

    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            Socket s;
            try {
                while((s = sock.accept()) != null){                 
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());                       
                    String filename = dis.readUTF();
                    long size = Long.valueOf(dis.readUTF());

                    byte[] b = new byte[1024];

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename), true);

                    long read;

                    do{
                        read = dis.read(b, 0, b.length);
                        fos.write(b, 0, b.length);
                    }while(!(read < 1024));

                    System.out.println("Recipient: Done");
                    fos.close();
                    dos.close();
                    dis.close();
                    s.close();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
    t.run();

}
```

Error (After 1086464 out of 1513308160 bytes were transmitted. [1062 * 1024]):

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at main.sender$1.run(sender.java:60)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: does it fail at the same place each time? after the same number of bytes, same amount of time?

Comment: unrelated: but change to fos.write(b, 0, b.length); to fos.write(b, 0, read); and change read to an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is here in the recipient..

```
                do{
                    read = dis.read(b, 0, b.length);
                    fos.write(b, 0, b.length);
                }while(!(read < 1024));
```

You are saying to only loop while `read` is not less than 1024. Any `read()` operation can return a value less than the maximum buffer length at any time, even if the stream is not "at the end". Especially when network sockets are involved. The number of read bytes may be greater than 0 but less than 1024 on any read because that's simply how many bytes are available to the stream at that time.

The read call is giving you all the data it has (which fits the buffer) at that time, without having to block.

Try changing it to..

```
                int read;
                while ((read = dis.read(b, 0, b.length)) != -1 ) {
                    fos.write(b, 0, read);
                }
```

You had this kind of loop in the sender and it is correct (although you don't need the flush within the loop).

This kind of bug is more common than you might think. I'v seen it a lot over the years, even in "enterprise products". It doesn't get picked up and fixed because most of the time it works... until it doesn't.

Another issue above is that you were always writing `b.length` bytes to the file, regardless of how many bytes had actually been read into the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I will test it out as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The transmission now runs fluently.